# Set different colours for different HTML tags

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, gvim, color

Can we set different colours for different tags in HTML syntax? For example, set `a` tags to green and `div` tags to yellow. In VsCode [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jzmstrjp.color-the-tag-name)  makes HTML tags coloured inside `.html`, `.jsx`, `.tsx` and so on. How can we do this in Vim and Neovim?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Comment: Thanks, no your answer is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enrich the `html` syntax.

You can create a `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/html.vim`:

```
highlight Green guifg=Green
syntax match Green /<a\>[^>]*>/

highlight Yellow guifg=Yellow
syntax match Yellow /<i\>[^>]*>/
```